# How to make generic Counting Sort Method?

Tags: java, generics

Okay I am a pretty beginner java coder, and I am doing an assignment where I am stuck.  I need to create a generic method (sort) that sorts a Type array according to frequency, basically, I am taking the CountingSort Algorithm and making it a generic method.  This is where I am lost.  I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

Here is a link to my instructions,
 https://classes.cs.siue.edu/pluginfile.php/7068/mod_assign/intro/150mp08.pdf

Code:
Driver Class

```
package mp08;

public class Main {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Lists array = new Lists();
   array.populateLists();
    System.out.println("Original Int List: \n");
   array.sort(Lists.intList);
    System.out.println("Sorted Int List: \n");

    }

}
```

Lists Class

```
package mp08;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;


public class Lists {
public static Integer[] intList;
public static Integer[] sortedintList;
public static Integer[] frequency;
public static Character[] charList;
public static Character[] sortedcharList;
public static int MAX_SIZE = 101;
public static int lengthInt;
public static int lengthChar;

public Lists(){
    this.intList = new Integer[MAX_SIZE];
    this.sortedintList = new Integer[MAX_SIZE];
    this.charList = new Character[MAX_SIZE];
    this.sortedcharList = new Character[MAX_SIZE];
    this.frequency = new Integer[MAX_SIZE];
    this.lengthInt = 0;
    this.lengthChar = 0;
}

//Makes random integer for populated lists method.
public int randomInt(int min, int max){
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max-min)+1)+min;
    return randomNum;
}

//Makes random character for populated lists method.
public char randomChar(){
    String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    int N = alphabet.length();
    Random rand = new Random();

    char randomLet = alphabet.charAt(rand.nextInt(N));
    return randomLet;
}

//Populates intList and charList with random values.
public void populateLists(){
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++) {
       intList[i] = randomInt(1,100);
       lengthInt++;
    } 
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++) {
        charList[i] = randomChar();
        lengthChar++;    
    }    
}



//Returns sorted array
public Integer[] sorted(){
return intList;
}



  public static <T> void sort(T[] array) {

// array to be sorted in, this array is necessary
// when we sort object datatypes, if we don't, 
// we can sort directly into the input array     
Integer[] aux = new Integer[array.length];

// find the smallest and the largest value
int min = 1;
int max = 101;

// init array of frequencies
int[] counts = new int[max - min + 1];

// init the frequencies
for (int i = 0;  i < array.length; i++) {
  counts[array[i] - min]++;
}

// recalculate the array - create the array of occurence
counts[0]--;
for (int i = 1; i < counts.length; i++) {
  counts[i] = counts[i] + counts[i-1];
}

/*
  Sort the array right to the left
  1) Look up in the array of occurences the last occurence of the given value
  2) Place it into the sorted array
  3) Decrement the index of the last occurence of the given value
  4) Continue with the previous value of the input array (goto set1), 
     terminate if all values were already sorted
*/ 
for (int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    aux[counts[array[i] - min]--] = array[i];
}


  }
     public static void main(String[] args) {

Integer [] unsorted = {5,3,0,2,4,1,0,5,2,3,1,4}; 
System.out.println("Before: " + Arrays.toString(unsorted));

Integer [] sorted = sort(unsorted);
System.out.println("After:  " + Arrays.toString(sorted));

  }
}
```

I obviously have not finished my driver class yet and I would appreciate any help I can get!

Comment: The link requires signing in (and up!). Can you please paste the instructions here?

Comment: yes one sec! 1.  https://gyazo.com/2aa207b057beabb600ef4a5172d3af14

Comment: 2 https://gyazo.com/5dc86111a6cb56a11f1dba34580ad02b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no generic way for any `Comparable` type to get its ordinal number. Sometimes such numbers do not exist at all (for example, `String` is `Comparable`, but you cannot map any `String` to the integer number). I can propose two solutions.

First one is to store counts not in the array, but in `TreeMap` instead creating new entries on demand (using Java-8 syntax for brevity):

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void sort(T[] array) {
    Map<T, Integer> counts = new TreeMap<>();

    for(T t : array) {
        counts.merge(t, 1, Integer::sum);
    }

    int i=0;
    for(Map.Entry<T, Integer> entry : counts.entrySet()) {
        for(int j=0; j<entry.getValue(); j++)
            array[i++] = entry.getKey();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[] data = { 5, 3, 0, 2, 4, 1, 0, 5, 2, 3, 1, 4 };
    System.out.println("Before: " + Arrays.toString(data));

    sort(data);
    System.out.println("After:  " + Arrays.toString(data));

    Character[] chars = { 'A', 'Z', 'B', 'D', 'F' };
    System.out.println("Before: " + Arrays.toString(chars));

    sort(chars);
    System.out.println("After:  " + Arrays.toString(chars));
}
```

Such solution looks clean, but probably not very optimal (though its advantage is that it does not care whether all numbers are from 1 to 100 or not).

Another possible solution is to create some additional interface which defines ordering for given type:

```
public interface Ordering<T> {
    int toOrdinal(T obj);
    T toObject(int ordinal);
}

public class IntegerOrdering implements Ordering<Integer> {
    @Override
    public int toOrdinal(Integer obj) {
        return obj;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer toObject(int ordinal) {
        return ordinal;
    }
}

public class CharacterOrdering implements Ordering<Character> {
    @Override
    public int toOrdinal(Character obj) {
        return obj;
    }

    @Override
    public Character toObject(int ordinal) {
        return (char)ordinal;
    }
}
```

Now you may make your sort method accepting the ordering parameter:

```
public static <T> void sort(T[] array, Ordering<T> ordering) { ... }
```

Every time you need to get counts array index by `T` object, just call `ordering.toOrdinal(object)`. Every time you need to get object by array index, just use `ordering.toObject(index)`. So, for example, instead of

```
counts[array[i] - min]++;
```

Use

```
counts[ordering.toOrdinal(array[i]) - min]++;
```

And call the sorting method like this:

```
sort(characterArray, new CharacterOrdering());

sort(integerArray, new IntegerOrdering());
```